# communicating between fragments when only one of them is visible

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem with comuunicating between fragments that are chnged dynamicaly, i mannaged to use the interface system to cimmunicate if the fragments are all viewble but when i am viewing them sepretly i can't use a their actions since they dont have a tag yet, any thoughts?

main activty

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, Communicator {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (isSingleFragment()) {

        Button btn_color = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_color);
        Button btn_text = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
        Button btn_list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_list);
        btn_color.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_list.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_text.setOnClickListener(this);

        singleFragActions();

    } else {

        doubleFragActions();
    }


// some more stuff happens

@Override
public void apply(String data) {

    Log.d("data", data+"");
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Frag_list frag_list = (Frag_list) fm.findFragmentByTag("list");
//i cannot use id because the fragment in 
//MainActivity are in a layout and are enterd dynamicaly

    frag_list.addItem(data);

}
```

three fragments here, when on small screen, on is shown and three button on the top change them arrounf, if on tablet, all three are displyed, this is the interface

```
public interface Communicator {

public void apply(String data);

}
```

frag_text (first fragment)

```
public class Frag_text extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{


Communicator comm;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // stuff
return view;

}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    comm = (Communicator) getActivity();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    EditText input = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.frag_text_edit);
    TextView output = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.frag_text_show);

    String text_get = input.getText().toString();
    output.setText("hello "+text_get+" how are you today?");

    comm.apply(text_get);
}
}
```

frag_list (other fragment)

```
public class Frag_list extends Fragment{



ArrayList<String> list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_list, container, false);

list = new ArrayList<String>();



ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_frag);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

return view;

}

public void addItem(String data){

    list.add(data);
}
}
```

how to i access the other fragment if it doesnt have a tag yet?

Comment: your problem is getting fragment class instance in Activity?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, since its not on the screen i have not given it a TAG yet and it has no idea cause it is inserted in a frame layout

Comment: can't you use `Frag_list frag = new Frag_list()` check if its attached and then call the method required

Comment: @Raghunandan thank you i only just started with fragments, can you show me how to check if its attached? right now i get NullPointExeption on the list fragments add method if i instanciate the way you suggested

Comment: you should not http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()

Comment: Two quick possible ways to communicate: 1) SharedPreferences / onSharedPreferenceChanged, 2) Each fragment is known to the activity, so it can call some sync function, like Activity.addMessage / activity.popMessage. These two functions would naturally call a Queue or something. Additionally, the .addMessage function could trigger an event through an interfce so that the target fragment would know that the event actually happened.

Comment: @velis shared preferences is not meant for this

Comment: It is a very ineffective method of communication, but it DOES provide communication. I would prefer the second method though, but it's a bit harder to implement. The first method works with but a few lines of code. Good for a quick test, but not much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to know what fragment you will be calling then FragmentActivity could act as a mediator in this case, as it is a mere "host".  You already have this Communicator interface. Have it communicate to a given fragment:

```
public interface Communicator {
    public void apply(String data, String tag);
}
```

And the override:

```
@Override
public void apply(String data, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Frag_list frag_list = (Frag_list) fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    //Fallback plan in case the fragment has not been created.
    if(frag_list == null) {
        frag_list = new Frag_list();
        //Include the fragment for future reference.
        //This fragment has no view
        fm.beginTransaction().add(frag_list, tag);
    }
    frag_list.addItem(data);
}
```

And modify the fragment to always have the list available:

```
public class Frag_list extends Fragment{

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//...

    public void addItem(String data){
        //Add check to avoid problems
        if(list != null) {
            list.add(data);
        }
    }
}
```